# JavaScript parsing nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot (using discord.js)
I'm writing a help command using pages in embeds, I have the pages working fine - however, the problem seems to come when trying to get the data from the JSON.
I have the JSON file setup in a larger config file, so it's nested inside of it.
Each command has it's name attached to it

```json
{
    "other-json-data": "other data",

    "commands": {
        "rule": {
            "info": "This command gives the rules",
            "expectedArgs": "<number>"
        },
        "invite": {
            "info": "Invite new users",
            "expectedArgs": "<no-args>"
        },
        "flip": {
            "info": "Flip a coin",
            "expectedArgs": "<no-args>"
        }
    },

    "other-json-data": "other data"
}
```

I need to get the data from the `commands` area for each page.
I only have a integer input (from the page number), but I haven't got a clue how I would get the data from whatever command needs to be shown.

For something else in my project, I am using this to get the expectedArgs from the JSON object `config.commands[arguments].expectedArgs`, where the config is just a reference to the JSON file, this works perfectly fine. The arguments is a string input (i.e. `rule`), which returns whatever the info from that command.

However, would there be a way to get say the second one down (`invite`). I've tried `config.commands[pageNumber].expectedArgs}`, however, this doesn't seem to work. pageNumber would be an integer, so would it would get whatever value and then I could grab the `expectedArgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all keys from an object and select one using their index.

```js
const json = {
  "other-json-data": "other data",
  "commands": {
    "rule": {
      "info": "This command gives the rules",
      "expectedArgs": "<number>"
    },
    "invite": {
      "info": "Invite new users",
      "expectedArgs": "<no-args>"
    },
    "flip": {
      "info": "Flip a coin",
      "expectedArgs": "<no-args>"
    }
  },
  "other-json-data": "other data"
}
const pageNumber = 1
// key will be a command name, e.g. 'invite'
const key = Object.keys(json.commands)[pageNumber]
const { expectedArgs } = json.commands[key]

console.log(`${key} expects ${expectedArgs}`)
```

Remember that indexes range starts at zero.